# How to clear selected value in angular-ui select2

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select2

Im using angular-ui select2 plugin I cant find any solution for clear the selected input. how to clear the selected input ? thanks.

```
<http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview>
```

I want somethig like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options:

1 - You could use standart attribute `allow-clear="true"`

```
  <ui-select ...>
    <ui-select-match allow-clear="true" ...>{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    ...
  </ui-select>
```

OR

2 - You could add a button

```
<ui-select-match placeholder="Select or search a country in the list...">
  <span>...</span>
  <button class="clear" ng-click="clear($event)">X</button>
</ui-select-match>

$scope.clear = function($event) {
   $event.stopPropagation(); 
   $scope.country.selected = undefined;
};
```